# How to stack multiple matrices?

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix 'mat' and I would like to stack it k times

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
mat \\
mat \\
mat \\
mat \\
mat \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}$$

such that the result is also a matrix. I tried Join and ArrayFlatten but it did not seem to work. Especially the fact that k is supposed to stay arbitrary makes it really difficult for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mat = Array[a, {3, 3}];

k = 5;
stacked = ArrayFlatten[ConstantArray[{mat}, k]]

Row[MatrixForm /@ {mat, stacked}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Array[mat &, k, 1, Join] == 
Join @@ ConstantArray[mat, k] ==
Flatten[ConstantArray[mat, k], 1] == 
ArrayFlatten[ConstantArray[mat, k], 1] ==
stacked
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

Using the same `mat` and `k` as those in @kglr 's post, here is another option:

```
KroneckerProduct[ConstantArray[1, k], mat]
```

Comment: This is the mathematically elegant answer. :)

Comment: @J.M.isaway thx :)